# Maya Python 3x - Select Edges Based On Normal Angle

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, maya

I am pretty new to python and scripting/coding in general.

I am currently working on a small script that serves the purpose of selecting edges of an object in my scene, based on their angle. I have two intfields for the user to specify a min and a max value. Based on the input, I want a button to select all edges within the min/max range.
Everything works so far, except when clicking the button, the min/max input is NOT taken into account. Maya only selects all edges with the default value of 0, 
instead of selecting all edges in the min/max range and I can't figure out why.

From my limited knowledge, it seems the "selEdges" function is the issue.
The "ab=" flag usually takes two integer values and if i define it like this: ab=(0, 30), it works, but I don't want it hard coded. I just can't get my head around how to pass the user input from the two infields to the "selEdges" function.

Here is my script:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

if cmds.window('myWindow', exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI('myWindow')

cmds.window('myWindow', title='myWindow', wh=[200, 100])

cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2)

minNormalAngle = cmds.intField(minValue=0, maxValue=360)
minNA = cmds.intField(minNormalAngle, query=True, value=True)

maxNormalAngle = cmds.intField(minValue=0, maxValue=360)
maxNA = cmds.intField(maxNormalAngle, query=True, value=True)

def selEdges(*pArgs):
    cmds.polySelectConstraint(m=3, a=True, w=2, ab=(minNA, maxNA))
    cmds.polySelectConstraint(m=0)

def sofEdges(*pArgs):
     cmds.polySoftEdge(a=180)

cmds.button(label='select', command=selEdges)
cmds.button(label='soften', command=sofEdges)

cmds.showWindow()
```

Here is a screenshot for better understanding of the UI in maya.
!(http://abload.de/image.php?img=selscriptq9kcy.jpg)

**EDIT:**

This is what i have now:

```
# Selection Script by David Sikorsky 
#Alpha Version 0.5 

# - NOT FEATURE COMPLETE
# - BUGS MAY OCCURE WHILE USING THIS SCRIPT

import maya.cmds as cmds
import functools


# Close window if it already exists
if cmds.window('myWindow', exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI('myWindow')

# Create a Window
myWindow = cmds.window('myWindow', title='Selection Script', resizeToFitChildren=True)
# Column 1: How To Text
cmds.columnLayout('columnLayoutName01', adjustableColumn=True)
cmds.frameLayout('layoutFrame01', label='How To Use:', collapsable=True, collapse=False, borderVisible=False)
cmds.separator(h=1, style='none')
cmds.text('howTo', font='boldLabelFont', label='How to use:', align="center")
cmds.separator()
cmds.text('desciption', font='boldLabelFont', align="center", label='''- Select an Object in your scene.
- Specify min/max Edge Angle.
- Select all Edges In Range.
- Soften or harden or Selected Edges.''')
cmds.separator(h=1, style='none')
cmds.setParent('..')

# Column 2: Soft/Hard Text
cmds.rowColumnLayout('columnLayoutName02', numberOfColumns=3, cw=[(1, 102),(2, 20), (3, 102)])
cmds.text(label='<-Soft->', align='center', font='boldLabelFont')
cmds.separator(h=1, style='none')
cmds.text(label='<-Hard->', align='center', font='boldLabelFont')
cmds.setParent('..')

# Column 2: min/max Text
cmds.rowColumnLayout('columnLayoutName03', numberOfColumns=7, cw=[(1, 51), (2, 51), (3, 20), (4, 51), (5, 51)])
cmds.text(label='Min', align='left')
cmds.text(label='Max', align='right')
cmds.separator(h=1, style='none')
cmds.text(label='Min', align='left')
cmds.text(label='Max', align='right')
cmds.setParent('..')

#Column 3: Infields
cmds.rowColumnLayout('columnLayoutName04', numberOfColumns=7, cw=[(1, 50), (2, 2), (3, 50), (4, 20), (5, 50), (6, 2), (7, 50)])

def selSoftIRFunc(*pArgs):
    minSoftNA = cmds.intField(minSoftNormalAngle, query=True, value=True)
    maxSoftNA = cmds.intField(maxSoftNormalAngle, query=True, value=True)
    cmds.polySelectConstraint(m=3, t=0x8000, a=True, w=2, sm=0, ab=(minSoftNA, maxSoftNA))
    cmds.polySelectConstraint(m=0, a=False)

minSoftNormalAngle = cmds.intField(minValue=0, maxValue=180, enterCommand=selSoftIRFunc)
cmds.separator(h=1, style='none')
maxSoftNormalAngle = cmds.intField(minValue=0, maxValue=180, enterCommand=selSoftIRFunc)
cmds.separator(h=1, style='none')

def selHardIRFunc(*pArgs):
    minHardNA = cmds.intField(minHardNormalAngle, query=True, value=True)
    maxHardNA = cmds.intField(maxHardNormalAngle, query=True, value=True)
    cmds.polySelectConstraint(m=3, t=0x8000, a=True, w=2, sm=0, ab=(minHardNA, maxHardNA))
    cmds.polySelectConstraint(m=0, a=False)

minHardNormalAngle = cmds.intField(minValue=0, maxValue=180, enterCommand=selHardIRFunc)
cmds.separator(h=1, style='none')
maxHardNormalAngle = cmds.intField(minValue=0, maxValue=180, enterCommand=selHardIRFunc)

cmds.setParent('..')

#column 4: Buttons Layout
cmds.rowColumnLayout('columnLayoutName05', numberOfColumns=3, cw=[(1,102),(2,20),(3,102)])
for i in range(3):
    cmds.separator(h=5, style='none')

cmds.button(label='Select Edges', command=selSoftIRFunc)
cmds.separator(h=5, style='none')
cmds.button(label='Select Edges', command=selHardIRFunc)

for i in range(3):
    cmds.separator(h=5, style='none')

def softEFunc(*pArgs):
    cmds.polySoftEdge(a=180)

cmds.button(label='Soften Edges', command=softEFunc)
cmds.separator(h=5, style='none')

def hardenEFunc(*pArgs):
    cmds.polySoftEdge(a=0)

cmds.button(label='Harden Edges', command=hardenEFunc)

for i in range(3):
    cmds.separator(h=5, style='none')

def selSoftEFunc(*pArgs):
    cmds.polySelectConstraint(m=3, t=0x8000, w=2, sm=2)
    cmds.polySelectConstraint(m=0)

cmds.button(label='Select Soft Edges', command=selSoftEFunc)
cmds.separator(h=5, style='none') 

def selHardEFunc(*pArgs):
    cmds.polySelectConstraint(m=3, t=0x8000, w=2, sm=1)
    cmds.polySelectConstraint(m=0)

cmds.button(label='Select Hard Edges', command=selHardEFunc)

for i in range(3):
    cmds.separator(h=5, style='none')

def selInvertFunc(*pArgs):
    cmds.InvertSelection('*', tgl=True)

cmds.button(label='Invert Selection', command=selInvertFunc)
cmds.separator(h=5, style='none')
cmds.setParent('myWindow')

# Close Button Layout
cmds.rowColumnLayout('columnLayoutName06', numberOfColumns=3, cw=[(1,102),(2,20),(3,102)])
def closeCallback(*pArgs):
    if cmds.window('myWindow', exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI('myWindow')
for i in range(20):
    cmds.separator(h=10, style='none')
cmds.button(label='Close', command=closeCallback)
cmds.showWindow('myWindow')
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you be a little more specific tho? from my understanding i store the value of both intfields in two different variables, minNA and maxNA, so, if the value equals the user input, how can they always be the same?

Comment: You are using `cmds.intfield` for both `min` and `max`. Is that how it is done in Maya? The two intfields must differ somehow.

Comment: intfield is just the command to add an initger input field to the UI. So two infields = two input fields. One for the min and one for max value. i edited my initial post with the link to a screenshot.

Comment: OK. Shouldn't you read minNA and maxNA in your `selEdges` function? In your code, the function uses the global minNA that you've read once, just after the creation of the control, so it is probably 0.

Comment: you are right, that worked. i feel silly now, thanks a lot tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd want to do this with a sequence like this:

1. convert the current selection to edges
2. apply a polySelectConstraint to the selection to winnow it down
3. reset the polySelect constraint so it doesn't interfere with future selections

It's a good idea to write that function so it *doesn't* change the selection, since it's easy to accidentally deselect things with a bad value.   The minimum version would be something like this (notice how it resets the selection at the end)

```
def edges_by_angle(selection, min_angle, max_angle):
    '''return the edges in selection with a crossing angle between <min_angle> and <max_angle>'''
    result = []
    try:
        edges = cmds.polyListComponentConversion(selection, te=True)
        cmds.select(edges)
        cmds.polySelectConstraint(mode =3, type = 0x8000, a = 1, ab = (min_angle,max_angle))
        result = cmds.ls(sl=True) or []
    finally:
        cmds.polySelectConstraint(dis=True)
        cmds.select(selection)    
    return result
```

You can simplify the GUI by using an `intFieldGrp` instead of two `intFields`. It's a good idea to get in the habit of building your gui inside a function -- the code you have written above will work in the listener but will behave oddly if imported from a module file.  Putting things into a function is a cheap way to control the scope of the variables so there's not difficulty in figuring out where the callback functions you need are living.  Here's a very minimal example:

```
def selection_window():

    # callbacks
    def select_by_angle(a, b):
        old_sel = cmds.ls(sl=True, o=True) or []
        new_sel = (edges_by_angle(old_sel, a, b))
        if new_sel:
            cmds.select(new_sel)

    def smooth_edges(*_):
        cmds.polySoftEdge(a=180)

    def harden_edges(*_):
        cmds.polySoftEdge(a=0)

    # gui....
    w = cmds.window(title='select by edges')
    c = cmds.columnLayout()
    ifg = cmds.intFieldGrp(label = 'angles', nf = 2, cc = select_by_angle)
    cmds.rowLayout(nc=2)
    cmds.button('Soften', c= smooth_edges)
    cmds.button('Harden', c= harden_edges)

    #show the window and return it if you need it's name later...
    cmds.showWindow(w)
    return w
```

You can keep the `edges_by_angle()` function separate from this because it's likely to be useful in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Flags `a`, `w` and `ab` are only available in Vertex, Edge, Face and Texture Modes. You need to use `polySelectConstraint()` in Edge Mode.

Here is a Python version of code you should add to your script:

```
cmds.polyListComponentConversion( te = 1 )
cmds.ls( sl = 1 )
```

Look also at MEL equivalent:

```
ConvertSelectionToEdges;
string $sel[] = `ls -sl`;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.

i set the mode to edges by definig t=0x8000 within the select function. 
that wasnt the problem tho. is has been solved by reading minNA and maxNA from inside the fuction rather than outside of it

Comment: it was usefull, tho not to my specific problem. i upvote anyways, i have less than 15 posts tho, so it wont show